# Windows Phone 7 Map List Best Practices

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

On the IPhone, the map control allows you to switch between a list mode and map mode easily. I've been trying to find examples of this for WP7 but am at a loss.

Is there a best practice for implementing a list of objects on a map?

If not, do we just do it manually, I.E. Save the dataset and display it as a listbox or something?

If you do it manually, where is the best place to put a button to switch you between the 2 screen styles? I feel like that app bar isn't right.

I don't want to copy the IPhone UI standard and have a button in the title bar, although I'm running out of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one "best practice" I'd take a look at how the default Bing Maps app works - it provides a "results list" text menu item accessible from the ApplicationBar - and this is displayed via a full screen dialog (at least I think that's what it is).

However, that is only one "best practice" - I don't think their UI is perfect for all apps.

Comment: This is the best answer, just wish I could get the code for the default maps app :) I like the page transition too where it animates each pin.

Answer (score 0):

Application bar is fine, just make sure the buttons are in the same positions for each bar and that toggling views 10 times does not require pressing Back 10 times to go to the previous page, maybe use a different page transition so it doesn't feel like every other transition on the app.

Comment: That was always my concern with the app bar transition, it does that default pop up from the bottom. Which makes you really notice you've changed pages. Can you suppress that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if both pages have an application bar, only the actual image icons swap out, the black bar stays put.